# Как расстянуть QGraphicsItem на QGraphicsScene

Tags: c++, qt

Есть ли какой-нибудь метод для того чтобы растянуть объект на конкретное значение по вертикали или горизонтали, или в ином случае через что это можно реализовать

Comment: Есть. QGraphicsItem::setTransform()

Comment: Спасибо большое!